# Unsorted Array and Sorted Array are returned with their elements in the same order

Tags: java, arrays

I'm not sure what's going on here, I've got two array variables, one of them has its elements unsorted, while the other one is meant to be a copy in order to maintain both the unsorted and sorted arrays instead of just using one and losing the information in the other one.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] unsortedArray;
    int[] sortedArray;
    boolean continueProgram = true;
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = new String();
    while (continueProgram == true) {
        unsortedArray = buildArray();
        sortedArray = unsortedArray;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unsortedArray));
        quickSort(sortedArray, 0, sortedArray.length - 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unsortedArray));
        returnPositions(sortedArray, unsortedArray);
```

Here's my code, I've used a quicksort to sort the elements, but only on the variable `sortedArray`, not in unsorted array, so I don't know why it is returned as if it were sorted when I it is to be printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a copy of your unsorted array before using it to sort:

```
sortedArray = new int[unsortedArray.length];
System.arraycopy( unsortedArray, 0, sortedArray, 0, unsortedArray.length );
```

When you write:

```
sortedArray = unsortedArray;
```

you aren't actually creating a copy of the array, you're just setting both variables to point to the same array - which you then sort.

Comment: I did not know this could happen. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're printing the unsorted array both times. Starting where you have your first println, try:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unsortedArray));
quickSort(sortedArray, 0, sortedArray.length - 1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
returnPositions(sortedArray, unsortedArray);
```

Comment: I was, for debugging purposes, to see if it would come out as sorted after applying the quicksort.

Comment: Please fix the code in your question then. @horsefeathers discovered a real issue in your code and if you had taken more time to post your question, he wouldn't have needed to spend time on an answer that is apparently not useful to you.