# How to reset a sorted array to unsorted in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am writing a program to compare different sort methods. I random generated 100,000 integers and store these data to an array. I want to apply the same array to different sort methods in order to do the comparison. (I think create class for each method may solve my problem. But I don't want to create too many class). So I decided to create one class called Sorts and bunch of sort functions under this class. I want to my sorted array reset to unsorted in order apply the same array to different sort method. Could anyone tell me how?

Generate data:

```
int size = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int [] data = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++){
        data[i] = (int)(Math.random()*(10*size));
        System.out.print(data[i]+" ");
    }
```

Create object:

```
Sorts sort = new Sorts(size, data);
```

Invoke：

```
switch(index){
            case "1" :
                System.out.print("\nYou select bubble sort\n");
                sort.bubbleSort();
                break;
            case "2" :
                System.out.print("You select quick sort\n");
                sort.quickSort();
                break;
```

My class:

```
class Sorts{
  private int size;
  private int data[];
  Sorts(int size, int [] data){
      this.size = size;
      this.data = data;
  }

  protected void bubbleSort(){
      int temp = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i< (data.length-1); i++){
          for (int j = 0; j<(data.length-1);j++){
              if(data[j]>data[j+1]){
                  temp = data[j];
                  data[j] = data[j+1];
                  data[j+1]= temp;
              }
          }
      }
      printResult();

  }


  protected void quickSort(){

  }

  protected void resetData(){

  }
}
```

Comment: well you can make a copy of the original array and sort that. Or google for knuth shuffle.

Comment: Your best bet would be to generate the original array. Then make a copy of the array and pass it to the sort algorithm. You could attempt to keep track of the original position, but that seems like more overhead that `System.arrayCopy(...)`

Comment: Create a copy of your unsorted array before using it to sort:

    sortedArray = new int[unsortedArray.length];
    System.arraycopy( unsortedArray, 0, sortedArray, 0, unsortedArray.length );

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsorted Array and Sorted Array are returned with their elements in the same order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055694/unsorted-array-and-sorted-array-are-returned-with-their-elements-in-the-same-ord)

Comment: @KevinO Thank you for the idea. I solved the problem by System.arrayCopy(); I will keep my eyes open for better solutions.

Comment: @e4c5 You mentioned both solutions. Thanks

Comment: @ADITYA Thank you for the link. It helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use `Collections.shuffle`, which takes a 'List' parameter. This would obviously mean converting your 'int[]' to 'List' (and back again).

- Here's the [java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) for 'Collections.shufffle'.
- See the 'Collections.shuffle' tutorial [on tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_shuffle.htm).
- There's also a sample array ('int[]') version [on Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsShuffle/article.html).

On another point, rather than implement it as you have, Ithink it's better to use the Strategy pattern to implement multiple sort mechanisms like this. For instance:

```
interface Sort {
    void sort(int data[], int size);
}

class QuickSort implements Sort {
    void sort(int data[], int size) {
        ...
    }
}    

class MergeSort implements Sort {
    void sort(int data[], int size) {
        ...
    }
}

etc...
```

As a further aside:

- this is only sorting ints so consider how to sort any type (and perhaps generics).
- some sorts (e.g. MergeSort) are stable and use new arrays to represent the sorted data. How can you return that to the caller? You can't set 'data' to your new array.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I solved by using array copy so far. I will try your idea as well.

Comment: That's fine Jeffery. For your purposes, I think it's just as good. It's probably worth becoming familiar with the 'Arras' and 'Collections' utility classes. Good luck studying sort algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Method shuffle of the class Collection

```
Collection.shuffle(yourList);
```

This will shuffle your list automatically without implementing an own function. 
After that you can convert the list back to an array. :)

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think for the usecase OP seems to have, the array just needs a reshuffling, this method reshuffles although there is no guarantee that it would reset it to the original array

```
private void reset(final int arr[]) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         int nextInt = rand.nextInt(arr.length);
         int temp = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[nextInt];
         arr[nextInt] = temp;
    }
}
```